# How to append html in Nuxt with universal mode

Tags: append, nuxt.js, universal

I try to append HTML in js file. It was OK for SPA mode.

But when I change to universal mode, the HTML can't be appended.

Then I try to set the timeout for append function and it's Ok. The HTML is appended successfully.
I don't understand the reason why?

I just a new member in nuxt, so please help me explain the reason why, and how can I append HTML without set timeout?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code you are using to try and implement appending html I can't be certain, but I suspect the process where the appending is to happen is taking place on the server, before it is rendered to the client.

To get around this you could implement the use of `process.client` to delay the appending.

```
if (process.client) {
  //do what needs to be done
}
```

The other option would be to use the `mounted` hook to call to append the html.

As I say, if you post the code you are trying to use it would be possible to show a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I just have a div in index.vue like this
<div id="anId">

And append HTML in indev.js
$('#anId').append('<div>append HTML</div>')

As you said: the process where the appending is to happen is taking place on the server,before it is rendered to the client.It mean it already append html on the server.
So when it is rendering to the client, I think in the client, it has to include what appended on the server.Is this right?Or just render the original file(index.vue)not include what appended.

I still confused about what will be rendered to the client?Please help me

Comment: The beauty of frameworks like Vue is that they have helpers for you to get away from having to directly manipulate the dom using `.append()`. It can also mean you don't have to add the overhead that including jquery brings. Try looking at [v-html](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML). Also, consider editing your question and including your index.vue code, or the relevant parts of it.